# Hypothetical scenario in which an innocent person is involved and dragged in

Tags: criminal-law

Let's suppose that a person, who has no longer anything to lose and willing to drag an innocent along with him, sends money to an innocent via bank, calls the innocent person by telling them "I sent you the money for [such and such illegal act]" and hangs out immediately and blocks the innocent's number.
The innocent of course, a per title, did nothing and every mean of comunication or electronic mean of the actual perpetrator is tracked, from bank accounts to phone number and social media, and the perpetrator does know this and by this is willing to involve this innocent person, and by the proper investigations, it is found that the perpetrator had contact with the innocent poor guy- What's the legal ruling on the innocent on this case? Can the innocent individual be dragged in court for messages and money he didn't ask for and for communications interactions not depending on him?

Comment: No one has any idea of what you're talking about.

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by "dragged in court"?  Sued?  Tried for a crime?  Required to testify as a witness?  And, in what jurisdiction is all of this taking place?

Comment: I mean taken in court as the only person contacted by the criminal and all of this found out by tracking techniques.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch It seems pretty clear what I'm talking about.

Comment: A generic jurisdiction in which most known crimes are considered crimes. There's no need to specify the jurisdiction here, because I'm talking about a generic crime that is considered such in a generic jurisdiction. Specifying the crime and the jurisdiction is just meaningless and rendundant

Comment: @abdul , you get 'dragged in court' for a specific crime, and within a specific jurisdiction. There are no laws (and no courts) that apply for all of earth. Some things are perfectly fine to do in China or Iran or wherever, and not in other countries. So without giving a country and a crime, your question is not answerable.

Comment: @abdul the whole concept of what various steps exist that might be labeled "dragged in court" is different in different jurisdictions - of which generally a court would only involved if the process reaches the *last* step out of many. E.g. would this result in being jailed for questioning? That can't be answered for "generic jurisdiction", the criminal law process, pressing charges, rights and treatment of suspects, even things like whether jail vs prison distinction exists - it all depends on the jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make this concrete. You transferred $50,000 to my bank account, call me, and on the phone you say "as we agreed, I transferred $50,000 into your bank account to kill my wife". All that knowing that the police is tracing all your calls.

The police would obviously contact me. And question me. And search my home. And find that I have never done anything criminal in my life, that I don't have a gun, that there's no evidence that I'm preparing to commit a crime, and that they have nothing but hearsay that I have any intention to commit a crime.. Nothing.

So they would leave my alone after a while. I would never end up in a court. I declare that the $50,000 looks like a present to me and you can't have it back. Or more likely, that the payment was part of an unenforceable contract, and you can't have it back. I'd probably talk to the inland revenue to make sure they don't come after me. I might have to pay taxes on the $50,000.

Comment: Well, they have more than hearsay. They have a bank record that shows that you just took $50K from someone to kill their wife. In most jurisdictions, that would be sufficient to get you arrested and tried. It would probably be enough to get you convicted

Comment: Richard, there is a bank record that someone paid you 50k; nothing else. As gnasher said, that is enough to get you investigated.  I don't know of any system where it would get you arrested, let alone convicted

Comment: @Richard so anyone can get jailed and convicted for things that didn't depend on him or their items, but just on them being known by a criminal.

Comment: @abdul - People get convicted of things they didn't do all the time. That's just the way the justice system works. You've only got three choices; like it, lump it, give money to the justice project

Comment: I honestly find it hard to believe. Thanks anyway for your contribution.

Comment: This may be valid for the US because you wrote that one would pay taxes for 50000 $ to the IRS, but what about a European jurisdiction?

Comment: In the US this strategy may work well if you are white, have a spotless record and are reasonably well to do. Otherwise, this may backfire pretty badly.

Comment: @Hilmar so basically a black individual is at the mercy of...anybody, right?

Comment: @Hilmar because if this is the case then everybody shouldn't be displaying their own IBAN code nor should they answer any unsaved-number call and moreover they should hope that anybody who has their number doesn't give it to any other person who happens to be inwardly untrustworthy.

Comment: @Hilmar moreover, as far as I know, a person should be judged  separately for each case, not on the basis of their own criminal record. For example if a person wrongs me, we get the issue in court, and shortly after I wrong them for a total different reason there should be another case delivered, not that the first case can be compromised. This is most likely another question I'm going to ask separately.

Comment: @Richard well yes, there are who get convicted for things they didn't do, but it is in a way in which there's a proof they took action in it or a suspicious item was at their disposal (a rifle in one's car, for example), but not in a way that materially doesn't have anything to do with it, because if that's the case then I take a photo of you (sake of argument), save it on my phone and pretend to check it with your face in order to pretend to have a match and incriminate you. "Oh yeah, that's him"

Comment: @Abdul - People have been convicted for far less, especially if they have a criminal past

Comment: Then the only thing one can do is to hope that it doesn't happen to them. BTW I find the main answer more convincing and logically more palatable.

Comment: @abdul: I'm just stating that there is a bias in the US which would make the strategy in this answer work differently well for different type of people. A much better strategy would be to immediately report this both to the bank and to the police.  You may still get questioned but since you have been open & upfront, the risk is low. Trying to cash in on the money is probably not the smartest thing to do , especially if you have already a criminal history. However, it's such an unrealistic scenario that I wouldn't loose sleep over it in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, but you never know what life reserves, because here where I live, during middle school, I used to be made guilty of things I never did, but it was to the level of slandering someone or making someone cry by saying things about their own family etc. The problem is that the same "teens" that were accustomed to make my life harsh in little school would do the exact same thing on a penal and legal lever if they ever have a chance.

Comment: I live in a little town in Italy, in which there's a certain distiction between poor immigrants like me and rich Italians in terms of everything, and false claims are rampant here. Here most likely an Italian would win a lawsuit against a North African immigrant. In these kind of issues perpetrators are getting sharper year by year. Yes, this scenario is not so likely, but anyway there are many in the same category but different features and metrics that can happen as well.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution